# How can strace monitor itself?

Tags: kernel, monitoring, recursive, strace

I have a hypothetical situation:

1. Let us say we have two strace processes S1 & S2, which are simply monitoring each other.
   How can this be possible?
   Well, in the command-line options for strace, `-p PID` is the way to pass the required PID, which (in our case) is not yet known when we issue the strace command. We could change the strace source code, such that `-P 0` means, ask user for PID. E.g., read() from STDIN. When we can run two strace processes in two shell sessions and find the PIDs in a third shell, we can provide that input to S1 & S2 and let them monitor each other.
   **Would S1 & S2 get stuck? Or, go into infinite loops, or crash immediately or...?**
2. Again, let us say we have another strace process S3, with `-p -1`, which, by modifying the source code, we use to tell S3 to monitor itself. E.g., use getpid() without using STDIN.
   **Would S3 crash? Or, would it hang with no further processing possible? Would it wait for some event to happen, but, because it is waiting, no event would happen?**

In the strace man-page, it says that we can not monitor an init process. **Is there any other limitation enforced by strace, or by the kernel, to avoid a circular dependency or loop?**

Some Special Cases :
S4 monitors S5, S5 monitors S6, S6 monitors S4.
S7 & S8 monitoring each other where S7 is the Parent of S8.
**More special cases are possible.**

EDIT (after comments by @Ralph Rönnquist & @pfnuesel) :
https://github.com/bnoordhuis/strace/blob/master/strace.c#L941

```
if (pid <= 0) {
    error_msg_and_die("Invalid process id: '%s'", opt);
}
if (pid == strace_tracer_pid) {
    error_msg_and_die("I'm sorry, I can't let you do that, Dave.");
}
```

Specifically, what will happen if `strace.c` does not check for `pid == strace_tracer_pid` or any other special cases? Is there any technical limitation (in kernel) over one process monitoring itself? How about a group of 2 (or 3 or more) processes monitoring themselves? Will the system crash or hang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer for Linux only.

Surprisingly, in newer kernels, the `ptrace` system call, which is used by `strace` in order to actually perform the tracing, is allowed to trace the init process. The manual page says:

```
   EPERM  The specified process cannot be traced.  This could  be  because
          the  tracer has insufficient privileges (the required capability
          is CAP_SYS_PTRACE); unprivileged  processes  cannot  trace  pro‐
          cesses  that  they  cannot send signals to or those running set-
          user-ID/set-group-ID programs, for  obvious  reasons.   Alterna‐
          tively,  the process may already be being traced, or (on kernels
          before 2.6.26) be init(8) (PID 1).
```

implying that starting in version 2.6.26, you can trace `init`, although of course you must still be root in order to do so. The `strace` binary on my system allows me to trace `init`, and in fact I can even use `gdb` to attach to `init` and kill it. (When I did this, the system immediately came to a halt.)

`ptrace` cannot be used by a process to trace itself, so if `strace` did not check, it would nevertheless fail at tracing itself. The following program:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, getpid(), 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror(NULL);
    }
}
```

prints `Operation not permitted` (*i.e.,* the result is `EPERM`). The kernel performs [this check in `ptrace.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c#L320):

```
 retval = -EPERM;
 if (unlikely(task->flags & PF_KTHREAD))
         goto out;
 if (same_thread_group(task, current)) // <-- this is the one
         goto out;
```

Now, it is possible for two `strace` processes can trace each other; the kernel will not prevent this, and you can observe the result yourself. For me, the last thing that the first `strace` process (PID = 5882) prints is:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 5882, 0, 0x11
```

whereas the second `strace` process (PID = 5890) prints nothing at all. `ps` shows both processes in the state `t`, which, according to the `proc(5)` manual page, means trace-stopped.

This occurs because a tracee stops whenever it enters or exits a system call and whenever a signal is about to be delivered to it (other than `SIGKILL`).

Assume process 5882 is already tracing process 5890. Then, we can deduce the following sequence of events:

1. Process 5890 enters the `ptrace` system call, attempting to trace process 5882. Process 5890 enters trace-stop.
2. Process 5882 receives `SIGCHLD` to inform it that its tracee, process 5890 has stopped. (A trace-stopped process appears as though it received the `SIGTRAP signal.)
3. Process 5882, seeing that its tracee has made a system call, dutifully prints out the information about the syscall that process 5890 is about to make, and the arguments. This is the last output you see.
4. Process 5882 calls `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, 5890, ...)` to allow process 5890 to continue.
5. Process 5890 leaves trace-stop and performs its `ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 5882, ...)`. When the latter returns, process 5890 enters trace-stop.
6. Process 5882 is sent `SIGCHLD` since its tracee has just stopped again. Since it is being traced, the receipt of the signal causes it to enter trace-stop.

Now both processes are stopped. *The end.*

As you can see from this example, the situation of two process tracing each other does not create any inherent logical difficulties for the kernel, which is probably why the kernel code does not contain a check to prevent this situation from happening. It just happens to not be very useful for two processes to trace each other.

Comment: +1 ; Nice analysis !! I will be taking some time to analyze this further, but it does sound Practical & logical !!

Answer (score 10):

```
% sh -c 'exec strace -p $$'    
strace: I'm sorry, I can't let you do that, Dave.
```

:-)

Comment: Is the quote actually correct?

Comment: That's what happens for me. Made my day :-)

Comment: Yes, for me, too, and I didn't know about it, so +1. But I'm just wondering, if the quote should not be: `I'm sorry, Dave, I can't let you do that.`. ;-)

Comment: You're right, it's "Dave Bowman: Open the pod bay doors, HAL.
HAL: I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."

Comment: +1 , Would you believe me if I said my initial thinking was about "self-aware" Processes, moving on to "Artificial Intelligence" ? It seems to be leading to 2001 . . . .

Comment: My question still remains : Why prevent this ? What will happen (at kernel level) in case of 2 (or 3 or more) Processes monitoring each other ? Will system hang or crash ? What are the technical limitations ?

Comment: I imagine, You could end up in a deadlock, or short memory , if a process would monitor itself. If

Answer (score 3):

Just want to show you a real example of circular Dependency or loop which could cause the system freeze.

In your X session and graphical terminal emulator, run this command to get the Xorg.bin pid:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ pgrep Xorg
1780
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$
```

Then do:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ sudo strace -p 1780
```

It will freeze entire desktop after a few seconds (~5), at least in my fedora 21 gnome 3.14.0, i have to turn off the power button.

But if you try either run `sudo strace -p 1780` in the other tty via Ctrl-alt-F1|7 OR `sudo strace -p 1780 2>/tmp/strace.log`, both will not freeze.

So we can conclude that strace receive Xorg's output then print it to Xorg and cause infinitely loop and freeze.

Comment: +1 , I like this experiment. My interpretation is like this : When 1 Xevent happens, many (say around 10) system calls are made. Each of these system calls will have to be captured and printed by strace. Each of the strace prints will generate many (say around 10) Xevents. We now have 10*10 Xevents, which require 10*10*10 system calls, which will require 10*10*10 lines of strace output, which require 10*10*10*10 Xevents. Pretty quickly, this exponential growth will fill up the internal event queues or output buffers , hence the system will freeze. Well, it sure highlights a specific problem !

Comment: @Prem The other example is `strace -p "pid of terminal emulator A"` in terminal emulator A, same conceptual above except might take longer to freeze and it only freeze the relevant terminal emulator(s). And one more example is `konsole strace gnome-terminal` and `gnome-terminal strace konsole`, both will freeze. When testing, use mouse to hover the terminal emulator will generate a lot of log and freeze soon.